# Sql query for multiple ANDs use in a single condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an SQL query , with multiple AND's. Let me explain with an example,

For example I want to search in a database for a property , who's price is greater than 1000 and less than 2000 (price is between 1000-2000), and its area is greater than 1000 sqft. and less than 2000 sq ft. (area is between 1000-2000).
So i was guessing that the query could be,

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (price>1000 AND price<2000) AND (area>1000 AND area<2000)
```

this is something i need ! Thank you

Comment: Your query is fine.  What is your question?

Comment: this query can work fine ?

Comment: The query fits your description. Do you have a problem with it (or with the results)?

Comment: Yes , it wasnt showing the result, until i have used the BETWEEN word, now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query looks fine to me, but you can also use [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) if you like, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (price BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000) AND (area BETWEEN 1001 AND 2000);
```

> expr BETWEEN min AND max
>
> If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type. Otherwise type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments

Comment: This is **not** the same as `(price>1000 AND price<2000) AND (area>1000 AND area<2000)`

Comment: `BETWEEN` is inclusive.  The OP seems to want *exclusive* ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Use between instead of and

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (price between 1001 AND 1999) AND (area between 1001 AND 1999)
```

Comment: BETWEEN is inclusive. The OP seems to want exclusive ranges. You are also leaving out the possibility that the values are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, i think it will solve your problem. It works for me:

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE price and area BETWEEN 1001 and 1999.

If we have same values of the parameters, then we can add the condition with and all the parameters.